# Why does search view shows only 160 items?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

[image]In customer master, when I entering the state I clicked search more option. It lists only 160 items where actually it contains more than that. So I checked it found that the search view only list 160 items even the master file contain more than that.

#### addons/web/static/src/js/views/form_common.js

```
dataset.name_search(search_val, self.build_domain(), 'ilike', 160).done(function(_data) {
    self._search_create_popup("search", _data);
}        `
```

When changing 160 to 161, the search form shows 161 items.

So how can I set this to unlimited (ie. as much as the items there) and moreover is it safe to change the value within Odoo? Or how can I do this in other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Partner form, the State field has a `domain` that is enforced if your partner has their *Country* selected. This means that if you choose "United States" as the *Country*, then it will only show *States* that also have a *Country* of "United States"

However, even when the *Country* is not selected, it will still restrict the number of *States* shown in the *Search more...* popup.

I'm not sure why, but if you:

1. Click the *Search...* bar in that popup window
2. Press *Enter* (to re-search the list)

Then it will return all available *States*...

It seems that this is a known issue with no plan to fix (at least not to backport to stable versions once it is fixed). See these Github Issues reports (below). This still exists on Odoo 11, even on [demo.odoo.com](https://demo.odoo.com)

1. [Search more unpredictable](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/17490)
2. [[V8] only 80 of 160 taxes are shown: reality 2651](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2235)

There are ways to work around this issue, but it requires modifying the JavaScript (as you mentioned it in your question, you may have some idea about this already). You can see [this question](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/why-does-product-search-view-not-show-all-products-75669) on the Odoo forum, which has a couple of snippets.

Basically, the solution requires overriding the `name_search` function out of `addons/web/static/src/js/framwork/data.js`

```
name_search: function (name, domain, operator, limit) {
    # This is the magic
    limit = 0;
    # Just the above line
    return this._model.call('name_search', {
        name: name || '',
        args: domain || false,
        operator: operator || 'ilike',
        context: this._model.context(),
        limit: limit || 0
    });
},
```

Note: This will globally affect all of your Odoo. If you want to restrict it to only one form (or some other criteria), then you must do so with whatever view/template you use to define your JavaScript import.

---

#### Previous Answer

The normal way to modify that is to change the default [`limit` of a Window Action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) in XML or the GUI and it will show more or less records by default.

1. Enable Developer Mode
2. Navigate to the Tree View that you want to remove limit from
3. Click the “Debug” button (bug icon in top right of Odoo, next to user name)
4. Click “Edit Action”
5. Change the “Limit” value and save

   - Limit of 0 or -1 should achieve an unlimited list, but you may need to test a couple of different values to see which works best.
   - If those don’t work well, then you can change Limit to 999999 or something higher than will ever conceivably be reached.

**Notes:**

1. You can also define that `limit` change via XML on the Action.

   ```
    <field name=“limit”>0</field>
   ```
2. You can also set the `limit` attribute on a `tree` element directly.

   Again, you may have to test this to see which value provides the unlimited list, but you can use it like this (in the tree view XML definition):

   ```
    <tree id=“...” string=“...” limit=“0”/>
   ```

Comment: I edited my question. Please see the screen shot attached. I need to change 160 to unllimited

Comment: Ok, so I think the issue is something else entirely. If you can, check that field to see if it has some `domain` defined. I will be able to give a more detailed response in a few hours, if needed.

Comment: there is no domain set.The issue is in odoo it is set as 160. I have mentioned the file and line in the question if i change that value to 200 the search form will shows items between 0-200. So is there any ways to inherit the js file or override this file? if so,then how to do it

Comment: @HVH Answer has been updated. You can make the change to the core file to see the difference, but I heavily recommend that you don't make any permanent changes to the core files. Instead, you should take the time to make your changes in a third-party module.